# Поиск и удаление экранирующих символов PowerShell с помощью регулярок

Tags: регулярные-выражения, powershell

Здравствуйте!

Есть текст вида:

```
$var = .\`[qwerty`] qwerty.txt.
```

Нужно найти экранирующие символы ``` "``" ``` (обратные кавычки) и заменить их.
Как это сделать с помощью регулярок?
Делаю так:

```
$var -replace "``[^.]+``"
```

Находит, заменяет, но вместе с текстом внутри этих обратных кавычек.
Т.е. получается:

```
.\] qwerty.txt
```

Как исключить все, что внутри?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужны обратные кавычки вместе с обратным слешем, то вот так:

```
\\?`
```

Найдет и обратный слеш с кавычной, и просто кавычку,

Иначе тут регулярное выражение не к месту.